# Samba permissions in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, samba

Looked high and low - but not able to get a clear cut answer / leads.

I am using 14.04 for file server. There are 4 users connected to this - each with their own pwds. All are shared to one group.

The file create and directory create mask are set to 0777 - thus it should be that each file and folder is shared to all other users. But it is not working like this.

I have also enabled recycle bin in the samba settings.

Would be grateful for some hints.

Rgds.

Comment: make sure  you have  changed ownership of shared  directory to new group  that you create and  also changed permission  and all user should be member of this group .  please provide behavior that you are getting that will be better for me to understand your problem .

Comment: The folder created by any one user is read only for other users. Except folders created by xx - where xx is the group owner.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this might probably fix your issue  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide   grts

Comment: Yes. I have looked at all these documentation before posting here.

Comment: Did the other ones the same in file sharing as well ?   http://www.howtogeek.com/74459/how-to-create-samba-windows-shares-in-linux-the-easy-way/

Comment: I have added the users as explained in the howtogeek article. the same settings were working earlier in 12.04. now we are having to change permissions again and again manually.

Comment: Well i could n´t come up with a better idea to assist a bit, but in  a home network or a network environment there has always been the same file share settings configured  to share properly,it is not the same as file sharing over cloud  i hope you could establish the file sharing like you want it to be